# If $C$ is the smallest angle of a triangle, SHOW $\sin(C/2)\leq 1/2$. What's the significance of $C$ being smallest?

Tags: trigonometry, triangle-inequality

> Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be the angles of a triangle, with angle $C$ as the smallest of them. Show that
>
> (i) $\sin \left(\frac{C}{2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{2}$
>
> (ii) Hence, or otherwise, show that $$\sin \left(\frac{A}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{B}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)<\frac{1}{4}$$

By applying Jensen's inequality, I am getting

$$\sin \left(\frac{A}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{B}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\leq\frac{1}{8}$$

iff $A=B=C=\pi/3$.

Comment: I rolled the question back to my revision, which has a more-informative title (and slightly-better formatting). Keep in mind that your question is one of potentially  *hundreds* that scroll by the reader every day; the better a title is at summarizing the specific nature of the question, the better the question's chances of being answered. The original title, "What is the significance of giving C is the smallest ANGLE?", doesn't mean a great deal by itself.

Comment: @Blue,How can u tell Sin(c)<= 1/2.U have to proof.

Comment: It's a reasonable interpretation of the title that a proof is being requested. (That said, maybe adding "show" would be helpful.) ... Anyway ... I see you've rolled the question back to your entirely-unhelpful title. I won't get into a rollback battle over this. If you insist on rejecting my improvements, that's up to you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the smallest angle $C\gt60^\circ$, it means that $A+ B<120^\circ$, which menas that either $A$ or $B$ must be smaller than $60^\circ$ i.e. smaller than $C$ which is a contradiction. So it must be that $C\le60^\circ$ and therefore:

$$\sin\frac C2\le\sin 30^\circ=\frac 12\tag{1}$$.

Now we know $A+B=180^\circ - C$

$$2\sin\frac A2\sin \frac B2=\cos\frac{A-B}2-\cos\frac{A+B}2=\cos\frac{A-B}2-\cos\frac {180^\circ - C}2=$$

$$\cos\frac{A-B}2-\sin\frac C2\tag{2}$$

Consider the maximum value the last expression in (2) can get. Obviously the first item should be as big as possible and the second one as small as possible. The first tiem can have a maximum value of 1 (in case $A=B$). For all other values of $A,B$, the first term is smaller. The second term is some positive number, definitively between 0 and $\frac 12$.

So the maximum value the expression (2) can get is actually smaller than 1 (the biggest value is achieved for $B=C$ and infinitesimally small value of angle $C$). For arbitrary values of $A,B,C$ it is now obvius that:
$$2\sin\frac A2\sin \frac B2\lt 1$$

$$\sin\frac A2\sin \frac B2\lt \frac 12\tag{3}$$

By combining (1) and (3) we get:

$$\sin\frac A2\sin\frac B2\sin\frac C2\lt\frac14$$

Comment: How A and B can always be equal?.Rather can it  be said, Maximum value of cos θ is 1.Henceforth, [cos(A/2−B/2)−sinC/2] always less than 1

Comment: I have clarified my answer. Maximum value of $\cos(A-B)$ is achieved for $A=B$. It's not mean that $A$ and $B$ are always equal. In all other cases $\cos(\frac{A-B}2)\lt 1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: (1) Use $3C\leq \pi$.

(2) Use (1) and convert the product of the first two factors into sum (of cosines).

Comment: Can u tell ,where will be  the implementaion of "C is the smallest angle" in this sum.

Comment: If $C$ is smallest, then $\pi=A+B+C\geq C+C+C=3C$.